# How to rename multiple directory from CMD prompt with different names

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How to rename multiple directory from CMD prompt with different names like below :

> alnaddy.com-7-5-2014 -> alnaddy.com
>
> cairoscene.org-7-5-2014 -> cairoscene.org
>
> elshaab.org-7-5-2014 -> elshaab.org
>
> goal.com-7-5-2014 -> goal.com

I have a list of thousands of directories .
thanks

Comment: Having dates in names suggests there may be some with the same base name. How to deal with them? Is the format reliable (`<string.ext> dash <rest>`)?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Stephan that this could be unsafe and/or unsolvable given that two folders could differ only in the date suffix.

But if I were confident that there would be no collisions, then I would use my [JREN.BAT regex renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081) - pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

Assuming all the folders are in a single parent, then I would execute the following from the parent folder.

```
jren "-\d\d?-\d\d?-\d{4}" "" /d
```

If I wanted to process the entire folder tree, then I would add the /S option.

Answer (score 0):

From the command prompt:

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims=-" %a in ('dir /AD /B') do ren "%a-%b" "%a"
```

If may be duplicate names after removing the date, you need a Batch file to manage the duplicates:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the maximum number of duplicate names (keep it low)
set "maxDups=4"

for /F "tokens=1* delims=-" %%a in ('dir /AD /B') do (
   set "newName=%%a"
   if exist "%%a" (
      for /L %%i in (%maxDups%,-1,1) do (
         if not exist "%%a (%%i)" set "newName=%%a (%%i)"
      )
   )
   ren "%%a-%%b" "!newName!"
)
```